# How can i escape all of the punctuation in a string with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new to creating websites using PHP, and I recently picked up a tip from a friend that if I escaped all of the data inputed from a form, then my website would be a lot less vulnerable to HTMLi and SQLi attacks. Let's say for example:

```
$_POST['name'] is equal to "<h1>You could have prevented this</h1>"
```

What will happen is on my website it will appear very large which is not good at all. I want it to display as

```
<h1>blabla</h1>
```

not

## blabla

Is there a simple function for this?

Comment: I'm not sure to see a diff between your two examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where you're putting the data.

If you're echoing it into a HTML page, use something like `htmlentities()`.

If you're putting it into a SQL string, use `mysqli_escape_string()` and/or use parameterized queries (`mysqli`'s "prepare", or PDO).

If you're echoing it into a JavaScript fragment on a page, use something like `json_encode()`.

The key point is that you need to use the *right escaping function for what you're doing*.

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` for when you output user input onto a page. This prevents XSS.

To prevent SQL Injection you should use a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (for example with PDO or MySQLi), not escaping. Escaping is a primitive way of preventing SQLi and it is not always 100% secure, unlike Prepared Statements which are (when used properly).

SQLi and XSS are different problems and should be solved separately. There is no one size fits all solution to prevent all types of vulnerabilities. Each type of vulnerability should be addressed individually.

Answer (score 0):

Your "tip" makes little sense as HTML and SQL attacks are different things. Yet, if you want to avoid problems with display, use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` to escape such data. If you want to take care of SQLInjection, use `mysqli_escape_string()` or equivalent (PDO escapes automatically)